# Spring Boot OAuth2/OpenID Connect Client An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed Jwk set

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-provider

I'm implementing single sign on authentication for Spring Boot application using OpenID Connect.I have configured Spring Boot Oauth2 client in my application with third party OpenID Connect authorization server.
For Spring, I followed configuration [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect). My client, redirect uri are registered with the OpenID Provider.
Using above configuration, when user tries to access any protected resource, the application redirects to auth server login page,wherein user submits login credentials.After this point my application fails with error

```
2021-08-20 17:26:07.481 DEBUG [dashboard,,,] 113904 --- [o-8443-exec-161] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP POST https://{domain}/oauth2/token
2021-08-20 17:26:07.485 DEBUG [dashboard,,,] 113904 --- [o-8443-exec-161] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2021-08-20 17:26:07.487 DEBUG [dashboard,,,] 113904 --- [o-8443-exec-161] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{grant_type=[authorization_code], code=[BrHZBSzmXT4uvuUHfhyuhnyuhuh], redirect_uri=[https://{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/abc]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
2021-08-20 17:26:07.902 DEBUG [dashboard,,,] 113904 --- [o-8443-exec-161] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2021-08-20 17:26:07.905 DEBUG [dashboard,,,] 113904 --- [o-8443-exec-161] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
2021-08-20 17:26:08.160 DEBUG [dashboard,,,] 113904 --- [o-8443-exec-161] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET https://{domain}/oauth2/jwk/jwtotp
2021-08-20 17:26:08.162 DEBUG [dashboard,,,] 113904 --- [o-8443-exec-161] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
2021-08-20 17:26:08.191 DEBUG [dashboard,,,] 113904 --- [o-8443-exec-161] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2021-08-20 17:26:08.191 DEBUG [dashboard,,,] 113904 --- [o-8443-exec-161] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [java.lang.String] as "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
2021-08-20 17:26:08.215 DEBUG [dashboard,,,] 113904 --- [o-8443-exec-161] .s.o.c.w.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter : Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_id_token] An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed Jwk set

org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_id_token] An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed Jwk set
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.createOidcToken(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:226) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:155) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.java:185) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:160) [spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at com.sso.oidc.config.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:37) [classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:555) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Malformed Jwk set
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.createJwt(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:155) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder.decode(NimbusJwtDecoder.java:129) ~[spring-security-oauth2-jose-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.authentication.OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.createOidcToken(OidcAuthorizationCodeAuthenticationProvider.java:223) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

I'm not sure why this error happens, spring should be internally decoding the JWT token using the key recieved through jwk-set-uri.
The logs don't have much information to provide.

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
//@Import(TrustStoreConfig.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/oauth2/**", "/login/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().oauth2Login().authorizationEndpoint()
                .authorizationRequestRepository(new InMemoryRequestRepository()).and()
                .successHandler(this::successHandler);

    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
logging: 
  level: 
    org.springframework.security.oauth2: DEBUG
    org.springframework.web: TRACE
server: 
  port: 8443
spring: 
  security: 
    oauth2: 
      client: 
        provider: 
          abc: 
            authorization-uri: https://{domain}/oauth2/authorize
            token-uri: https://{domain}/oauth2/token
            user-info-uri: https://{domain}/oauth2/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: sub
            jwk-set-uri: https://{domain}/oauth2/jwk/jwtotp
        registration: 
          abc: 
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            client-id: ****
            client-secret: ***
            scope: openid,email
            redirect-uri: https://{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/abc
```

This is what my Spring Configuration looks like. I couldn't find much information regarding why this happens and how to resolve it. In [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect) everything seems to be managed by Spring internally and there is no such mechanism to decode JWT.
Please guide upon this.

Comment: This is an error that Nimbus returns when it cannot parse the JWK Set response from the authorization server. I'd recommend hitting the https://{domain}/oauth2/jwk/jwtotp endpoint to see what you get. Also, I've opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10222 to hopefully add more detail to the error.

Comment: I did try to hit https://{domain}/oauth2/jwk/jwtotp endpoint and it returns set of keys. `{
    "keys": [
        {
            "kty": "RSA",
            "kid": "****", "use": "sig",
            "n": "************************************",
            "e": "AQAB"
        },
        {
            "kty": "RSA",
            "kid": "****",
            "use": "sig",
            "n": "******************************************",
            "e": "AQAB"
        },...]}`

Comment: please dont write code in comments, as you can see its completly unreadable. Update your question instead

Comment: You might consider using Nimbus's API to parse the JWK set in a test. `RemoteJWKSet` is the one that Spring Security uses.

Answer (score -2):

I think you encountered an error setting your "authorization uri". Take a look. I believe the correct one would be;
I hope I helped.

```
 ...
            .antMatchers("/oauth2/authorize**", "/oauth2/**" ..
```

Comment: it was typing error, actually it is "/oauth2/authorize" and the authorization uri works perfectly fine, the application do gets redirected to login page and also it processes the /token after this, you can see this in log.